# Javascript: how to insert value into text input fields from a drop down menu

Tags: javascript

I am pretty new to javascript so I hope someone here can help me out with this little task.

I currently have two input text fields that I need to be populated with text after selecting an option from a drop down menu.

For example...

I have a select field that looks like this:

```
<select id="select_2" onchange="insertProduct(2);">
```

And within that select I have options that look like this:

```
<option id="cdrom001" title="my cdrom">cdrom001 - my cdrom</option>
<option id="DVD-ABUG" title="A Bug's Life">DVD-ABUG - A Bug's Life</option>
<option id="DVD-BELOVED" title="Beloved">DVD-BELOVED - Beloved</option>
....
```

What I want to happen, is when I select an option from that drop down list, I want my text input field #1 to be populated with the option id (eg. DVD-ABUG) and I want my text input field #2 to be populated with the option title (eg. A Bug's Life).

Here is the code for my two text input fields:

```
<input type="text" name="model[]" id="model_2">
<input type="text" name="product[]" id="product_2">
```

I have this much written of the function that will be required to do this...

```
function insertProduct(id){ 
// code goes here
}
```

As you can see, I don't have much. :o)

Can someone please help me with the function that can do this?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line:

```
<select id="select_2" onchange="insertProduct(2);">
```

to this:

```
<select id="select_0" onchange="insertProduct(this, 0);">
```

and use this function:

```
function insertProduct(select, row){ 
    var model = "model_";
    var product = "product_";
    document.getElementById(model + row).value = select.options[select.selectedIndex].id;
    document.getElementById(product + row).value = select.options[select.selectedIndex].title;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that works great.  However, it's not dynamic in the fact that I can't use it in a loop because the model_2 and product_2 need to change to model_3, product_3 etc... any idea how to work around that?

Comment: add var model = "model_"; and var product = "product_"; to the top of the function. Then put the two lines from above (the document.getElement... ones) in a for loop. Then change the parameters of the getElementById calls, so that "model_2" becomes "model + (i + 1)".

I'll edit my original answer to reflect this.

Comment: Thanks for the reply... I added the two variables to the function but not quite sure how to construct the for look, can you help me please?

Comment: well there are two fields per row.  the number of rows is dynamic, just depends upon how many the user wants.

Comment: and each row will have the same drop down menu next to it.

Comment: I just changed the function to reflect the function you have and now it inserts the values into all of the rows.  I need it to just insert the values into the same row as the select field.  For example, lets say there are six rows, with each row having the two text input fields as well as a select field next to it.  You have the choice of six different select fields, and so when you select an option for one of those six select fields, it needs to insert the values into the two text input fields on the same row only.  Does that make sense?  Thanks btw for all your help, you're a life saver.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. I updated the select tag and the function above again.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you are looking for Just call it on `onchange` instead of button click

http://www.mredkj.com/tutorials/tutorial002.html